# asp.net caching implementation for popular content

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

In the following code i want to achieve this: every time a user asks for a specific piece of content, i first check if I already got this content from the DB on **the same day**.
If so - I shall return the cached content. If not - i first re-retrieve the content from the DB ,return it to the user and cache it for the next requests from this day, and so on ..
What i want to know is if it is a good code practice for saving (a lot of ) DB time on popular content . (I care less about how the code example looks, as just made it up for this question and it's not going to be used as-is in my app ..)

the code example:

```
public class ContentCachingExample
{
    private static DateTime _lastRequestTime;
    private static MyContent _cachedContent;

    private static MyContent GetContent()
    {
        // compare dates - content will be re-retrieved from DB once a day.
        if (DateTime.Now.Date> _lastRequestTime.Date) 
        {
            _lastRequestTime = DateTime.Now;
            _cachedContent = GetContentFromDb();
        }
        return _cachedContent;
    }

    private static MyContent GetContentFromDb()
    {
        // get content from DB
    }

    public class MyContent
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public int Property2 { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is a common pattern.

You should consider some of the libraries that exist, particularly if you ever need to fine-tune the caching mechanism.

David has mentioned System.Web.Cache

There is also [Enterprise Library Caching Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664753%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx)

However, if you only need the current capabilities of your code, then what you have is fine.

Comment: There is no valid reason to use anything like the code you have posted, the ASP.NET `Cache` object is nearly as simple, is proven, solid and will be far more performant.  As I point out, implementing this caching may not improve performance and may makes things worse.  This **IS** premature optimisation and if you truly care about your apps performance enough to consider this, consider it properly.

Comment: If you are using .NET 4, you should also explore the native System.Runtime.Caching

Comment: @Kieren - Far more performant?? How so? You have no idea how it works internally - back up your statement with a critique of why the above is not performant... Unless the quantity of data being cached is large in comparison with the available memory, then this is simply common sense and I would have serious questions about any web-developer working for me, who did not grasp this principle.

Comment: @BonyT - for example, the above code keeps the data in memory, even if the system is out of memory.  It will hold onto it to the end of time.  The ASP.NET `Cache` uses `WeakReferences` internally (**oh look, I know how it works internally**), and so if the system is low on memory, you won't have a massive problem.  Therefore, the ASP.NET `Cache` object is a far, far better choice than rolling your own, like the above.  I would have serious doubts about working for someone who wanted to reimplement the ASP.NET cache

Answer (score 2):

Yes, DB caching is part of best practice and can make very large performance gains. If you rely on it too heavily you can end up with very dispirit performance, say after the IIS worker has just restarted compared to once it has been running an hour.

Remember to think about cache expiration, what if this popular content changes? How long before you uses see the new content? You get a lot of the performance boost for cache times a lot smaller then 24 hours, if you have a page view a second a cache time of 1 minute will save you 59 trips to the DB and mean if a page gets slashdoted you have a (small) chance of surviving.

If you are using MS-SQL there are ways to [invalidate caches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx) if a row or a table changes

You may also want to investergate [output caching](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111708/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121306-1.aspx) if you are using ASP.NET, this allows you to cache the result from a page or a control, based on the URL parameters. This allows you to save web server CPU as well as DB load with your caching.

try using [System.Web.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bx0tk8a.aspx)

```
private MyContent GetContent(){
   MyContent content = Cache[GetContentCacheKey()];
   if(content == null) {
     content = GetContentFromDb();
     Cache.Add(GetContentCaceKey(), content, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), 
          Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.High, null);
   }
   return content;
}
```

Comment: OP's question: "What i want to know is if it is a good code practice for saving (a lot of ) DB time on popular content" - ?

Comment: The code you give is exactly what i needed, but you didn't mention if it were a good practice in the first place ..

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone Yea type faster then I read :), I have updated my answer to include my belief that caching is good practice

Answer (score 0):

This is known as premature optimisation.  You're attempting to solve a problem that you (presumably) don't know exists.

This is often harmful.  For example, if you are experiencing bad performance right now, it could be because you are constrained by memory: for example, running SQL Server and IIS on the same machine, and it's too much.  In that case, the caching-DB-content strategy would not help, it would make things worse.

If the DB query in question takes a long time to retrieve (as *measured directly* by you, and *confirmed* that it's too long for the user to wait: you really must do these two steps), then you might consider something as you suggested.  You will want to look into the ASP.NET `Cache` object, rather than reinvent it yourself, though.  A quick google turns up this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx which might be a good starting point.

Unless you have a performance problem, don't attempt to solve it now.  You can develop with things like this in mind - that's why you should develop apps with clear separation of concerns, modularity, tiered structure, service architecture etc: you could easily add a 'caching layer' later, **if needed**.

Comment: Caching regularly used resources is most certainly NOT premature optimisation - it's good practice.

Comment: It most certainly IS premature optimisation.  Take my example: what if the DB queries return in 10ms and the machine is running at 100% RAM use?  It is **by definition** premature to optimise an app to store the results of a DB query in memory and assume that it is a bottleneck.  How is that not optimisation, which is premature?  Because the nature of the speed issue (*if any*) isn't known, it would be premature to optimise based on an unknown issue

Comment: I disagree in general - with my solution i only need to execute the db query once per day . Whereas running the query again for each user means I will run it as much as my visit count (which could be big,if the site will succeed .. ).

Comment: You asked if it was bad coding practise.  It is good idea to consider caching, it is a very bad idea to apply it without knowing the situation more fully than you appear to.

Comment: @Kieren - I see - and do you also not provide any logging, tracing, exception handling, threading etc. etc in your code for the same reasons??

Comment: No, because they are instantly and in themselves useful.  Clearly you are confused.  Premature optimisation = may have negative gain and provide no benefit whatsoever.  Could wreck performance.  Logging = required and useful straight away.  Tracing = required and useful straight away.  The difference is, here, you're implementing caching **to attempt to improve performance**, when you may be screwing it up.  You don't implement those other things to improve performance.